# How to send data from FCM's onMessageReceived() to Fragment?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mvvm, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to receive data in my app:

```
class CustomFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(msg: RemoteMessage?) {
        val data = msg?.data ?: return
        val name = data["name"] as String
        val age = data["age"]?.toIntOrNull() ?: return
        val bio = data["bio"] as String
        val img1 = data["img1"] as String
        val match = Profile(name, age, bio, img1, null, null)
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived(): $name is $age")
        val fcmViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FcmViewModel::class.java) // .of() only takes a fragment/activity
        FcmViewModel().match.postValue(match)
        Log.d(TAG, "Value: " + FcmViewModel().match.value.toString()) // null
        super.onMessageReceived(msg)
    }
```

When I receive the FCM, I want to pass it to my Fragment. I've tried to use LiveData + ViewModel, but unfortunately, `postValue()` isn't actually changing the data in the ViewModel from the service because I can't instantiate a reference to the ViewModel from a service.

```
class FcmViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val match: MutableLiveData<Profile> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Profile>()
    }
}

class MapFragment : Fragment() {

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            fcmViewModel.match.observe(this, Observer<Profile> { profile ->
            log("${profile.name} is ${profile.age}") // doesn't print
        })
    } 
}
```

Is there a better way to pass data from `FirebaseMessagingService()` to my fragment or a way to post data to `FcmViewModel()` within the `FirebaseMessagingService()`?

Comment: A bit of a hacky solution would be to have the livedata object in your `Application` class then your fragment could subscribe from there and your service could also post from there. Otherwise I would say abstract out the livedata from the viewmodel into its own repository class which both the viewmodel and service could reference with some dependency injection

Answer (score 18):

With a `LocalBroadcastManager` marked as deprecated, it' seems like there is no standard way of doing this now.

However `LiveData` has nothing to do with `ViewModels`. You can still use `LiveData`. I would recommend @tyczj's solution which he has commented. Or you can do following.

Create a singleton class which will work as your small event bus framework. This singleton class can have list of `LiveData` which you need and both `Fragment` and `Service` can access instance of LiveData. Service and Fragment can act as a lifecycle owner, so you will not face any problem.

Below is a sudo code

```
object Events {
    val serviceEvent: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
    }
}

class CustomFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(msg: RemoteMessage?) {
        Events.serviceEvent.postValue(profileObj)
        super.onMessageReceived(msg)
    }
}
class MapFragment: Fragment {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Events.serviceEvent.observe(this, Observer<Profile> { profile ->
            log("${profile.name} is ${profile.age}")
        })
}
```

You can also create your own subclass of `LiveData` and control the data updates in `LiveData` by overriding `onActive` and `onInactive` functions

Comment: Thankyou this is good if the app is in the foreground. Would you know how to receive the FCM notification data in my Fragment if the app is in the background? (without clicking on the notification)

Comment: I am not sure, if FCM supports this. You have to click on the notification to access the bundle data. I have to check the latest documentation.

Comment: accept the answerrrr

Comment: @HardikTrivedi thank you. I need your comment. this method has a problem. I called observer as you did in for example: "FragmentMoreDetailt" and postValue in "notificationClass" . the problem is after receiving fcm notification and current fragment is "FragmentMoreDetail" , when I go back to previous fragment and open "FragmentMoreDetail" again , it is called again everytime without fcm notification received!

 Events.serviceEvent.observe(this, Observer<String> { status -> })
or
 Events.serviceEvent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<String> { status -> })

Comment: @NimaAzhd I spend a few mins on this after your query. And the quickest way to achieve this is to use StateFlow.  StateFlow will only emit new values if there is any change in the old value.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi Thank you for your concern. I doubt whether I tried it or not. But I switched to the eventbus library [ https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus ] which supports many features. I might try stateflow to see if it works. in my scenario when I got the fcm notification and I was in fragmentB it was working correctly but there was a strange problem. When I went back to the main fragment and went to fragmentB again, it happened again. It looked like the fcm was recently received again, but actually this new fcm was not received.